# $lookup with pipeline slower than expected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following `$lookup` aggregation stage:

```
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "target",
            let: {byTargetId: "$foreignTargetId"},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$targetId", "$$byTargetId"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        someTargetProperty: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "targets"
        }
    }
```

In my test DB, the stage before this one returns only 5 documents.  In this case none of those have the optional property `foreignTargetId` so I expect `byTargetId` to be `undefined` each time, and no document in `target` collection will match.

The thing is, the aggregation takes 1 second longer if I add this lookup stage (at the end).

If I execute this aggregation on `target` collection that is identical to the lookup pipeline with a `undefined` value for `byTargetId`:

```
db.getCollection('target').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: ["$targetId", undefined]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            someTargetProperty: true
        }
    }
])
```

then indeed this takes around 200ms, and 5x200ms = 1s so this makes sense.

Yet if I execute the same aggregation with a `null` value for `byTargetId`:

```
db.getCollection('target').aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: ["$targetId", null]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            someTargetProperty: true
        }
    }
])
```

then this executes in < 1ms.

1. What causes this large difference between equality match on `null` and `undefined`?
2. How can I skip the $lookup stage if `foreignTargetId` is absent in the input document for this stage?

BTW the reason I'm using a lookup pipeline here is that the documents in `target` are quite large and I only need `someTargetProperty` which is also in the index so the lookup can be done completely in memory.  I've noticed in other cases that this can be significantly faster than looking up the whole document and projecting later.  I won't accept answers that try to get around this issue by not using a $lookup with pipeline.